# how to find when someone's account was created on discord (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

so I am making a bot, I am looking to find how to get when a users account was created. I have tried:

```
let d = new Date(target.guild.joinedTimestamp);
    registeredDate = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ", " + d.toDateString();
```

where `target` is:

```
const target = message.mentions.members.first();
```

but when I run it and log the results of `registeredDate` it returns date that is not accurate.

Comment: The `guild.joinedTimestamp` seems to be the time that they joined the server, not created the account

Comment: yeah, so what is the one for registering on discord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `User.createdAt`

```js
const target = message.mentions.members.first();

// joined the guild
new Date(target.joinedAt);

// account created
mew Date(target.user.createdAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be `target.user.createdAt` so do this maybe.

```
  let target = message.mentions.members.first();
        if(!target) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user")
let d = new Date(target.user.createdAt);
registeredDate = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ", " + d.toDateString();
console.log(registeredDate)
```

Comment: no, still not working. just returned a random value that is not accurate.

Comment: Sorry it is `target.user.createdAt`, please look at my edited answer